# C pass static char array to function

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass down static char array from header to a function. The problem is that it's getting garbage strings for the first for-loop in microseq.c
How do I properly use static char strings in microseq.c?
I used Xcode(8.3.1) for this experiment.

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"
#include "microseq.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    printf("Program starts here \n");
    microseq_t *microseq0;
    microseq0=load_microseq(*init_seq);

    free(microseq0);
    return 0;
}
```

main.h

```
#ifndef main_h
#define main_h
#include <stdlib.h>

static char* init_seq[13] = {
    "000011000004",
    "0FF000200004",
    "240C00FE0C04",
    "3D0000001041",
    "000000001F0D",
    "00000241240C",
    "8000004DC124",
    "040001FD1E14",
    "00000003AD33",
    "04000FF00004",
    "232AAA2FFFFC",
    "00FFFFFFFFFF"
};

typedef struct microseq {
    char* algo; 
} microseq_t;

#endif /* main_h */
```

microseq.c

```
#include "microseq.h"

microseq_t *load_microseq(char* algo) {
   microseq_t *ptr;

    ptr = (microseq_t*) malloc(sizeof(microseq_t));
    if(!ptr) {
        return ptr;
    }

    int i;

    ptr->algo = algo;
    printf("function starts here\n");
    for (i=0; '\0' != *(ptr->algo+13*i); i++) {
        printf("From top: %s    \n", ptr->algo+13*i);
    }
/*
It's printing garbage strings in between
"From top: Program starts here 

From top: s here "
*/
    for (i=0; *(init_seq+i)!=NULL; i++) {
        printf("Directly from: %s   \n", *(init_seq+i));
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

microseq.h

```
#ifndef microseq_h
#define microseq_h
#include "main.h"
#include <stdio.h>

microseq_t *load_microseq(char* algo);

#endif /* microseq_h */
```

Output:

```
Program starts here 
function starts here
From top: 000011000004    
From top: 0FF000200004    
From top: 240C00FE0C04    
From top: 3D0000001041    
From top: 000000001F0D    
From top: 00000241240C    
From top: 8000004DC124    
From top: 040001FD1E14    
From top: 00000003AD33    
From top: 04000FF00004    
From top: 232AAA2FFFFC    
From top: 00FFFFFFFFFF    
From top: Program starts here 

From top: s here 

Directly from: 000011000004   
Directly from: 0FF000200004   
Directly from: 240C00FE0C04   
Directly from: 3D0000001041   
Directly from: 000000001F0D   
Directly from: 00000241240C   
Directly from: 8000004DC124   
Directly from: 040001FD1E14   
Directly from: 00000003AD33   
Directly from: 04000FF00004   
Directly from: 232AAA2FFFFC   
Directly from: 00FFFFFFFFFF   
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: Is it necessary to add "static" modifier to a field that is contained within a file you #include?

Comment: Do not assume that string literals are lined up as expected.

Comment: Since you've hard-coded the number of elements to 13, why not use that information to terminate your loop?  Also, I'd pass the array as char** along with the number of elements.  Finally, no idea why you need to use 'algo+13*i'  That alone seems like a red flag.

Comment: @NickMeyer: Yes; otherwise only one source file can include the header because it defines the array of pointers each time it is included.  You're probably hinting that the initialization shouldn't be in the header at all (and I'd agree with that), and then the variable should be declared `extern` and not `static`.

Comment: After `"00FFFFFFFFFF"`, add another string `""` to terminate `for (i=0; '\0' != *(ptr->algo+13*i); i++) {`  Accessing `*init_seq[12]` is UB.

Comment: @chux That's a good solution. It works well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @chux Would one of you like to create an answer?

Comment: @Yunnosch Even OP can now answer this.  Yet it is a bit of an odd program style and an answer that patches its problem does not seem to be of wider future application/reference.

Comment: Wouldn't you agree that Q/A pairs are always preferrable to Q/comment pairs? I mean even if the question is not impressive, interesting, widely useful or has a widely applicable answer.

Comment: @DiegoSunDevil In my test program, the width of column is fixed with the length of 12 chars, and will have several other static char arrays with various row sizes.